# Add a Unique ID Number To Duplicate Rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-update, window-functions

I have the below table called `TestTable` and need to update the `MsgNum` column to have a unique number ordered by the date column but grouped by the `JobNum`.

```
JobNum | MsgNum | Date 
320    | 0      | 2020-04-10 
320    | 0      | 2020-06-11 
320    | 0      | 2020-06-12 
330    | 0      | 2020-04-10 
330    | 0      | 2020-06-11 
330    | 0      | 2020-06-12
```

Below is what I need to end up with.

```
JobNum | MsgNum | Date 
320    | 1      | 2020-04-10 
320    | 2      | 2020-06-11 
320    | 3      | 2020-06-12 
330    | 1      | 2020-04-10 
330    | 2      | 2020-06-11 
330    | 3      | 2020-06-12
```

I have the below that seems to work to generate the ID number that but suck on how to update the table `MsgNum` column with the ID number.

```
SELECT [JobNum], [MsgNum]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [JobNum] ORDER BY [Date]) AS id
FROM [dbo].[TestTable]
```

Comment: Can you share what you have so far with the update command? Alternatively, have you considered rebuilding the table using your select statement i.e. creating a new table using your select statement and replacing the existing table  with your newly created table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and an updateable common-table-expression:

```
with cte as (
    select msgNum, row_number() over(partition by jobNum order by Date) rn
    from mytable
)
update cte set msgNum = rn
```

Comment: That worked  just changed mytable to TestTable and ran the statement and it updated the table exactly as required.

Thank you.

Comment: Update the statement below for my production table that needed the update and it worked perfectly.
'code
WITH IDNUM AS (
    SELECT [Conversation Id], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Parent Id] ORDER BY [Send Time]) ID
    FROM [dbo].[RequestEmail]
)
update IDNUM set [Conversation Id] = ID'